# How to return inside a try-catch in a recursive method?

Tags: java

I dont get why I cant return a value inside my code, there it is :

```
private int depth(Position<Integer> p) {
    try{
        if (ab.isRoot(p))
            return 0;
        else 
            return 1+depth(ab.parent(p));
    }catch(InvalidPositionException | BoundaryViolationException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}

}
```

It's not detecting the return. I know it is inside a try-catch and it could capture an exception, but I'm confused because in the book I'm reading (Data Structures and Algorithms - Goodrich & Tamassia 4th edition) he's not sending an int in the parameters (which could be usefull in the recursion to save the value)

EDIT: Solved, thanks you all!

Comment: "It's not detecting the return" is surely not the error you are getting from the compiler.

Comment: This method must return a result of type int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is "detecting" the `return`.

It's just that you don't have an explicit `return` on all program control paths: you need to return something in the `catch` block.

Personally though I'd mark the function itself as being able to throw the exceptions that you currently `catch`, and deal with the exceptions at the calling site. Your function then reduces to

```
private int depth(
    Position<Integer> p
) throws InvalidPositionException, BoundaryViolationException 
{
    return ab.isRoot(p) ? 0 : 1 + depth(ab.parent(p));
}
```

Comment: So If i just put this line it should works without any problem? 

}catch(InvalidPositionException | BoundaryViolationException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage()); return 0;}

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Miruuu only if it makes sense to use 0 as a default value. Otherwise, you should return a more appropriate value, or throw an exception (or not catch the exception, adding `throws` to the method signature).

Comment: Yes, I'll add the throws, i think it's better. And handle the exception outside. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to return from the `catch` block as well as in the case of an exception, the return statement inside the try block would never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature indicates it returns an integer and never fails (doesn't throw any exceptions).

Your implementation is not honoring this contract, if an exception is thrown in your code you catch it, but you don't return any value in that case.

You can fix it in two ways. You can either return an value in your catch block, or you can remove the try catch block and add the exceptions you are catching to your method's signature. Which solution is better depends on what exactly your code does, and how do you think it's going to be used.

Also keep in mind catching exceptions and just logging is a bad practice if you do it carelessly.